# BIRT chart: How to hide X axis ticks between labels?

Tags: javascript, charts, birt

I have a line chart with long-term results (365+ days). The X axis is a category axis, showing the day of sampling. This leads to at least 365 ticks while only 12 dates are shown.

What is needed to hide the ticks between the labels to get only 12 ticks, one for each label?